# (∀x ∈ X, P(x)) or (∀x ∈ X, Q(x)) ⇒ ∀x ∈ X,(P(x) or Q(x)) where X is nonempty and P(x) and Q(x) are statements.

Tags: logic

I know this is an obvious statement but how would one go about in showing that this is true ?

My answer is :

Consider the 2 cases;

Case 1)  ∀x ∈ X, P(x) holds.  Then clearly  ∀x ∈ X, P(x) or Q(x) holds as the truth value for P(x) is true for all x so the truth value of P(x) or Q(x) will also be true for all x.

Case 2) Same as case 1 but switch P(x) with Q(x) and Q(x) with P(x).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Answers to questions like this are weird to word lol

Comment: You are right : consider a "generic" $x$ then, if $P$ holds of it, i.e. $P(x)$ is true, by truth conditions for $\lor$ also $P(x) \lor Q(x)$ is true. This holds for an $x$ whatever ("generic"): thus holds for **all** $x$.

Comment: Ohh so i think a better way to word it is let x ∈ X arbitrary.  Then case 1 P(x) is true so clearly P(x) or Q(x) is true... and so on
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem**: $(∀x ∈ X, P(x))$ or $(∀x ∈ X, Q(x)) ⇒ ∀x ∈ X,(P(x)$ or $Q(x))$, $X \neq \emptyset$.

**Proof**: The statement we are required to prove is an implication, then we just assume the antecedent to derive the consequent (see [conditional proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof)). Here is a proof sketch:

1. Let $(∀x ∈ X, P(x))$ or $(∀x ∈ X, Q(x))$.
2. Observe that $∀x ∈ X, P(x)$ implies $P(x)$.
3. Similarly, note that $∀x ∈ X, Q(x)$ implies $Q(x)$.
4. If $∀x ∈ X, P(x)$ implies $P(x)$, it also implies $P(x)$ or $Q(x)$, ([disjunction introduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction)).
5. Analogously, if $∀x ∈ X, Q(x)$ implies $Q(x)$, it also implies $P(x)$ or $Q(x)$.
6. Since $x$ is arbitrary in $P(x)$ or $Q(x)$, it follows that $∀x (P(x)$ or $Q(x))$.
7. Since each of the disjuncts in (1) imply $∀x (P(x)$ or $Q(x))$, we can conclude that  $(∀x ∈ X, P(x))$ or $(∀x ∈ X, Q(x)$ implies $∀x (P(x)$ or $Q(x))$ as required (see [disjunction elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination) and implication introduction)